# Divisibile by 7 theorem check

Tags: number-theory

I have come up with a theorem to check if a number is divisible by 7.

A number is $\overline{abcdefg}$ will be divisible by 7 if the sum below is divisible by 7

> $$(-2)^0a + (-2)^1b + (-2)^2c + (-2)^3d + (-2)^4e + (-2)^5f + (-2)^6g$$

It is valid for any number of digits..
I can prove it mathematically..

So I need your help to check if this theorem aren’t present/known to the world or not.

If not, what can be done to publish it.

Comment: What do $a,b,c,\ldots$ represent? You haven't defined them. 
Without understanding your claim competely, I would suggest that you do not have your hopes up. Such rules are very well-understood for hundreds of years, these are not publishable.

Comment: If you believe the result is original, it could have been a good ideia to draft a paper and submit it to https://arxiv.org/ where some mathematicians publish time-sensitive results to ensure they're able to claim authorship. Then submit it to a good publication, where experts should check the validity and originality of your claim. Be careful that not much attention needs to be given if a poorly written paper is submitted. Good literature review is also important.

Comment: Does this check only work for $7$-digit numbers?

Comment: It is as cumbersome as dividing a digit by $7$. Divisibility tests tend to make it easier like in the case of $2,3,11$ etc. Do you think this would be practical to solve for a $20$ digit number?

Comment: Since the powers of $10$ are periodic $\pmod 7$, it is easy to come up with a divisibility test.  People don't like it much since you have to remember the values of $10^n\pmod 7$...the powers go $\{1,3,2,6,4,5,1,3,2,6,4,5,\cdots\}$.

Comment: I assume that $\overline{abcdefg}$ means that the digit sequence may be repeated. Is that correct?

Comment: Note that $1001 = 7 \times 11 \times 13$. See if you can use that to come up with a simpler divisibility test.

Comment: Abcdefgh are nothing but digits of a number like 123456788, this is a number divisible by 7.. so a=1, b=2 and so on.. I hope it is clear now

Comment: This is essentially the divisibility test on the [wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisibility_rule#Divisibility_by_7) where you double the last digit and subtract it from the number formed by the other digits. Then repeat the process with this new number, and so  on until you have a single digit left. This is almost the same as multiplying the digits by powers of $-2$ as you are doing, but easier.

Comment: BTW, you can simplify your method a little by reducing those multipliers mod 7. Eg, $(-2)^3=-8\equiv-1\mod7$. That reduces your multipliers to 1, -2, -3, -1, 2, 3, 1, …

Comment: Is there a reason why you didn't accept the answer you recieved?

Answer (score 2):

This is a trivial assertion if you understand modular arithmetic, which is absolutely basic in number theory.

Note that $1/(-2)\equiv 10 \pmod 7$, which implies your claim immediately.

However, this rule has disadvantages compared to the usual algorithm that decides if a number is divisible by $7$ or not (namely, break it up to $3$-digit numbers, add them with alternating signs, iterate...)

- Your method only decides if the number is divisible by $7$, it does not return the remainder $\pmod 7$
- Your method is very slow, it takes much more time to compute that expression than adding up $3$-digit numbers.

So I suggest you read about advanced number theory, and if you find an interesting open problem (that experts found interesting as well), work on it. 
But this result is unpublishable. 
In any case, congratulations for finding this method.

Comment: I was hoping that the OP would take my hint & discover the 3 digit method for himself. But I guess it's still a good exercise to prove why it works.

Comment: I think I have already finished my post (or maybe still typing it) when you made your suggestion, so I didn't see it. Sorry for that.

Comment: Not a problem! Your answer is fine.

Comment: I am not sure if I would say it is trivial. The reversal of the order of the digits when passing from base 10 to base -2 is a nice twist which looks somewhat surprising. But it is true: things like these have been studied before in more generality. For instance you (that is: @Ravi Goyal, not A. Pongracz) could look at this page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reciprocal_polynomial where the  assertion from the current answer  that '[the fact that $1/(-2) = 10 \mod 7$] implies your claim immediately' is (in slightly more general notation) listed as 'Property 2.'